# Running a Hadoop cluster on one machine

Tags: hadoop, virtual-machine, cluster-computing, bigdata, hadoop2

I am new to Hadoop environnement.
I wanted to know if it is possible to run a cluster(containing 2 or 3 nodes) on a single machine using virtual machines.

Any clarification will be welcome.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Virtual Hadoop Wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Virtual%20Hadoop):

> Cloud and virtualization need to be examined separately, but in all cases the answer is "Yes you can virtualize, and yes, you can deploy to the cloud, but you need to know the consequences and plan accordingly".

This wiki page is a good place for you to start thinking about how to setup Hadoop on your VM.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, We can install many VM's on a single machine. But if we consider(for example) cloudera VM 4.7, it need 4 Gb of RAM for each. So for 3 VM's 3*4 = 12 gb. And, addition to that your machine has its applications to run, it need atleast 2 Gb. So on an whole you need 14+ gb of ram . And, Harddisk partitions should also be made accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest, pseudo distributed mode in your case. Running multiple VMs on a single machine is obsolutely fine. But the RAM you should be enough to handle these VMs along with your main applications. In the pseudo distributed mode, we will be able simulate the multinode cluster but the only difference is all the daemons like Namenode, Resource manager, Data node, Node manager uses single JVM instead of running in different machines.

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/single_node_setup.html