# How do multiple WSL use different file systems?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I want to use WSL to implement function like virtual machine(for learing hadoop), because my pc's performance is poor.
I use following command to create 3 instances:

```
wsl --import <Distribution Name> <Install Folder> <.TAR.GZ File Path>
```

but I find them using same file system. I want 3 instances to work like 3 seperate pc.
Is it possible？

Comment: Related:  [Running a Hadoop cluster on one machine](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29416780/11810933)

Answer (score 0):

Your question might need more detail, because the answer *seems* fairly obvious, but let's see if we can get you in the right direction.

Because each WSL instance is a virtualized environment, you aren't going to improve file system performance unless you distribute each instance to a separate *Windows* drive.  For instance:

```
wsl --import Hadoop1 c:\wsl\hadoop1 image.tar --version 2
wsl --import Hadoop2 d:\wsl\hadoop1 image.tar --version 2
wsl --import Hadoop2 e:\wsl\hadoop1 image.tar --version 2
```

I'm not a Hadoop expert, but I would assume that `C:`, `D:`, and `E:` would need to be different *physical* drives.  If they are all on the same physical drive (even different partitions), then that drive's IO is being shared amongst the three.

And, of course, you probably aren't going to improve performance if you use one SSD and two HDDs.

Note that you should make sure that you are using WSL2 instances for this purpose.  WSL1 instances create their filesystem *directly* on the Windows drive, but WSL2 uses a virtual HDD (`ext4.vhdx`) for each image.

You can also `wsl --set-default-version 2` to make this the default for all instances (if you haven't already).